# Consider the following iteration procedure. Does it converge for any nonzero initial point? If not, why? If so, to what value?

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

Consider the following iteration procedure. Does it converge for any nonzero initial point? If not, why? If so, to what value?
$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} x_n + \frac{1}{x_n}$ Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to solve for convergence for this problem? I went to the [Wiki](http://Wiki) page it was kind of vague on regards of how to actually implement the convergence analysis though.

Comment: Why, of course the Wiki starting page is going to be kind of vague. Better look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method).

Comment: Maybe (or maybe not) the intended right-hand side is $\frac{1}{2}\left(x_n+\frac{1}{x_n}\right)$. Can you check? The way it is currently written it converges if $x_0=\pm\sqrt{2}$. I have not looked at what initial values give convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : As long as you don't get a fixed point, you can show that this type converges.  The only fixed points are $x = 0$ (not defined) and $x = \pm \sqrt 2$.

For initial value as the fixed points, the sequence is convergent. For all other initial values, if you start with a positive initial value, it converges to $\sqrt 2$, and for a negative initial value it converges to $-\sqrt 2$.

One neat trick is to assume it converges, and then put $y = x_{n+1} = x_{n}$ and solve for y. This gives you an idea of what is happening. Then you can reason out rigorously.

Comment: It doesn't converge for $x=0$ but does for $x=\sqrt2$.

Comment: For negative initial values the sequence converges to $-\sqrt2$.

Comment: Having the term $\frac{1}{x_n}$, $x=0$ is weird.

Comment: When you say $y = x_{n+1} = x_n$ are you saying to set the equation up like this: $y = \frac{1}{2} y + \frac{1}{y} $ and then solev for y?

Comment: @Shammy  Yes... because if it is convergent, then for large n, the value of $x_{n+1}$ and ${x_n}$ is going to be very very close..

Answer (score 1):

I would go with turning it into a Newton's Method problem.

Newton's Method is used to solve for $f(x)=0$: $$x_{n+1} = x - {f(x)\over f'(x)}$$
I would look for a function $f$ such that
$$x-{f(x)\over f'(x)} = {1\over2}\,x_n + {1\over x_n}$$ or
$${f(x)\over f'(x)} = {-1\over2}\,x_n + {1\over x_n}$$
This differential equation can apparently be solved using separation, with the solution $f(x)=C(x^2-2)$ for an arbitrary constant $C$. Now look up when Newton's Method converges, and apply it to this function.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the sign of all $x_n$ is the same as the sign of the initial value $x_0$, so it is sufficient to look at the positive $x_0$ only.

Consider the RHS function $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{x}$, $x>0$.

1. $\min_{x>0}f(x)=\sqrt{2}$ attained at $x=\sqrt{2}$ $\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad$ $x_n\ge\sqrt{2}$, $n\ge 1$.
2. $f(x)\le x$ for $x\ge\sqrt{2}$ $\quad\Rightarrow\quad$ $x_{n+1}\le x_n$, $n\ge 1$.

The monotonic sequence $x_n$ has a limit $a\in[\sqrt{2},x_1]$, thus converges. To find the value, set $x_n=a$ to the recursion and solve for $a$ to get $a=\sqrt{2}$.

P.S. Similarly for negative $x_0$.